# I upgraded to php 7 and the superglobal request is empty

Tags: php-7, superglobals

I updated from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.

every `$_REQUEST['some_var']` I do returns an error that it is not set...

is it normal that `$_REQUEST` is empty ?

Example :

```
echo $_REQUEST['login_ID']
```

returns

> Notice: Undefined index: login_ID in

Comment: Instead of "code something like this", can you post a SSCCE demonstrating the exact issue, with the exact error mesasage. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I Edited the post with a regular example

Comment: I also face same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `php.ini` file for `request_order`. Possible it is not set correctly.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

```
; This directive determines which super global data (G,P,C,E & S) should
; be registered into the super global array REQUEST. If so, it also determines
; the order in which that data is registered. The values for this directive are
; specified in the same manner as the variables_order directive, EXCEPT one.
; Leaving this value empty will cause PHP to use the value set in the
; variables_order directive. It does not mean it will leave the super globals
; array REQUEST empty.
; Default Value: None
; Development Value: "GP"
; Production Value: "GP"
; http://php.net/request-order
request_order = "GP"
```

Comment: Hi in my case I needed request_order = "GPC" (C for Cookies) thanks;)